# Nuxt run code clientside within server-side execution

Tags: nuxt.js

In nuxt, if I know the code running is in server-side context, is there a way to specify that some code should run once the client is rendered?

For example:

```js
if (process.server) {
   // we know we are server-side
   // run the following line of code client-side:
   window.doSomething();
}
```

I know that as a workaround I could put this code in `mounted`, but is there any way to specify to run client-side within any context?

For example, like a setTimeout, or some callback like (pseudo-code) `onClientSide( () => {} )`

Comment: `if (process.client)` mainly?

Comment: @kissu, no I want to specify a block of code within server-side context to run upon client rendering (as in my example).

Comment: Since the code will mainly run twice, once on the server and then on the client, double-checking if it's case #1 or #2 if pretty much the solution. It's not like it's done on a single-pass.